# Cannot deploy vapor to heroku (error while trying to use pkgConfig flags for CTLS: couldNotFindConfigFile)

Tags: swift, heroku, push, vapor

I got this error when try to push (after installing Kanna and Leaf Provider packages)

**console log:**
warning: error while trying to use pkgConfig flags for CTLS: couldNotFindConfigFile
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.
 !     Push failed

Comment: I saw a similar error: right after the warning i got 'Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app' but I have no idea what the reason is. What other problem you had? maybe it is the same as mine

Answer (score 1):

The 'could not find config file' warning is only a warning, it won't actually cause your compilation. If you look further up the log there should be a proper error?

Comment: I saw a similar error: right after the warning i got 'Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app' but I have no idea what the reason is. What other problem you had? maybe it is the same as mine